# JMeter 4 with JAVA version 10: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, windows-10, load

I ran a test script[jmeter.bat] on Java 10 I get the following output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.jmeter.util.HostNameSetter (file:/opt/apache-JMeter-4.0/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar) to method sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setHost(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.jmeter.util.HostNameSetter
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Sample result for a page:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException
Response Message: Non HTTP response message: handshake alert: Unrecognized name
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Heading

Comment: A: Probably nothing.  Do what the message suggests. *"Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.jmeter.util.HostNameSetter"*

Comment: Any feedback on answers ? If ok you should accept one and upvote so that answer is safely usable by others.Thanks

Comment: I downgraded java version to 8 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brenda, [JMeter 4.0](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) has support for Java 9 so it's good if you can downgrade the Java version to 9.

[Redline13](https://www.redline13.com/) now [supports JMeter 4.0](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/03/apache-jmeter-4-0-support/) that can help you to run the performance tests in AWS environment without infrastructure hassle.

Comment: I downgraded the java version to 8 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The warning has nothing to do with the real issue, it’s related to Java9 restrictions on modules access.

Your problem would be more related to mismatch in ssl algorithm, key size between client(jmeter) and server.

Show more details on request and jmeter.log